# Help with finding a rotation of a camera's image over a plane

Tags: trigonometry

Here is an image of what I am trying to work out: [image: https://i.imgur.com/IkNvoff.jpg]

The large box represents a flat plane. The smaller box represents what the camera image would look like.

The camera in this model can only rotate around the $Z$-axis, so no pan or tilt.

My question is how to calculate the rotation of the cameras view relative to the environment plane, given that the camera knows its coordinates and also knows the coordinates of any objects it can see on the plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to care about the centerpoint.

Evaluate

$$\phi=\arctan_2\frac{Y_B-Y_A}{X_B-X_A}$$ in both pictures. The requested $\theta$ is the variation of $\phi$.

(If you are sure that the zero angle reference of the camera is accurate, you can compute $\phi$ from the known absolute coordinates. But computing from the same data in both cases might be advantageous.)